# How to order variable in a boxplot with respective tukey test

Tags: r, position, boxplot, tukey

I used the code from r-graph-gallery.com that i adapted to my data.

I would like to do 6 boxplots in one graph and order them in a specific order, but then as I am doing the ordering, the tukey analysis doesn't order itself at the same time with it !

Do you know how I can improve it ?

This is the wrong order but the right tukey test representation :
[image: Graph with the wrong order]

And here the one that has the right order but not the right tukey test repartition.
[image: Graph with wrong tukey test position]

What should I do to get the right order for the TUKEY test as well ?

By the way does anyone knows how to get the "a" value for the highest mean of the tukey test and not the "c" ?

Thank you for your help !

Here is the code I used :

```
date<- (read.delim("SoilOBIoldtd.txt", header=TRUE))
# library
library(multcompView)
# What is the effect of the level on the CEC ?
model=lm( date$CEC_eff ~ date$level )

ANOVA=aov(model)
# Tukey test to study each pair of level :
TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(x=ANOVA, 'date$level', conf.level=0.95)
#This line is the difference between the two plots (using or ignoring this line)
date$level <- factor(date$level , levels=c("DAFS_Top", "DAFS_Down",
"CONV_Top","CONV_Down","Old_cocoa_Top","Old_cocoa_Down"))
# Tuckey test representation :
plot(TUKEY , las=1 , col="brown")
generate_label_df <- function(TUKEY, CEC_eff){
   # Extract labels and factor levels from Tukey post-hoc 
  Tukey.levels <- TUKEY[[CEC_eff]][,4]
  Tukey.labels <- data.frame(multcompLetters(Tukey.levels,reversed = FALSE)['Letters'])
  #I need to put the labels in the same order as in the boxplot :
  Tukey.labels$level=rownames(Tukey.labels)
  Tukey.labels=Tukey.labels[order(Tukey.labels$level) , ]
  return(Tukey.labels)}
# Apply the function on my dataset
LABELS <- generate_label_df(TUKEY , "date$level")
# A panel of colors to draw each group with the same color :
my_colors <- c(   rgb(143,199,74,maxColorValue = 255),  rgb(242,104,34,maxColorValue = 255),   rgb(111,145,202,maxColorValue = 255))
# Draw the basic boxplot
a <-boxplot(date$CEC_eff ~ date$level , ylim=c(min(date$CEC_eff ) , 1.1*max(date$CEC_eff)) , col=my_colors[as.numeric(LABELS[,1])] , ylab="CEC" , main="")
# I want to write the letter over each box. Over is how high I want to write it.
over <- 0.1*max( a$stats[nrow(a$stats),] )
#Add the labels
text( c(1:nlevels(date$level)) , a$stats[nrow(a$stats),]+over , LABELS[,1]  , col=my_colors[as.numeric(LABELS[,1])] )
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example? We don't have access to your data. Also, calling a data frame "date" is not wise. Perhaps "Soil" would be a better choice. ;)

Comment: you factor date$level before boxplot with the levels you want to plot with? e.g date$level = factor(date$level,levels=c("DAFS_Top",....))

Comment: @StupidWolf Yes this is what I did !

Comment: @Edward
The DATA I have looks like:
DAFS    Top     20

Comment: @Edward
The DATA I have looks like:
DAFS    Top     20
DAFS    Top     18
DAFS    Top     19 
CONV   Top     14
CONV   Top     15 
CONV   Top     16
Old coco  Top   14
Old coco  Top   13
Old coco  Top  13.5 
DAFS    Down   8
DAFS    Down   9
DAFS    Down   9.5
CONV   Down   8.5
CONV   Down   7.5
CONV   Down   7
Old coco  Down   5.5
Old coco  Down   6.0
Old coco  Down   5.5

Comment: why is date$level in quotes? generate_label_df(TUKEY , "date$level"). Can you remove the quotes? If this doesn't work, to help you, you needa do two things. 1. Provide a subset of the data, say 4 per group, with this we can see what's wrong, and two reduce your code to the essential parts

Answer (score 1):

Hey I think I got your problem, basically assigning a color /text label correctly to the boxplot.

Below I generate some data, did the Tukey, and got the labels out:

```
library(multcompView)

set.seed(111)
lvl = c("DAFS_Top", "DAFS_Down",
"CONV_Top","CONV_Down","Old_cocoa_Top","Old_cocoa_Down")
df = data.frame(CEC_eff=rnorm(48,rep(c(2,4,6),each=8),1),level=rep(lvl,each=8))

df$level <- factor(df$level , levels=c("DAFS_Top", "DAFS_Down",
"CONV_Top","CONV_Down","Old_cocoa_Top","Old_cocoa_Down"))

ANOVA=aov(lm(CEC_eff ~ level ,data=df))
TUKEY <- TukeyHSD(x=ANOVA, "level", conf.level=0.95)
LABELS <- multcompLetters(TUKEY$level[,4],reversed=FALSE)$Letters
```

Now you define the colors, and you can assign the letters to the colors.

```
my_colors <- c(   rgb(143,199,74,maxColorValue = 255),  
rgb(242,104,34,maxColorValue = 255),   rgb(111,145,202,maxColorValue = 255))

names(my_colors) <- sort(unique(LABELS))
```

Then we assign the color to the levels that would appear in the boxplot:

```
lvl_colors <- my_colors[LABELS[levels(df$level)]]
```

And plot:

```
a <-boxplot(CEC_eff ~ level , data=df, cex.axis=0.7,ylim=c(min(df$CEC_eff ),
1.1*max(df$CEC_eff)) , col= lvl_colors, ylab="CEC" , main="")

over <- 0.1*max( a$stats[nrow(a$stats),] )
#Add the labels
text(1:nlevels(df$level) ,a$stats[nrow(a$stats),]+over ,names(lvl_colors )  , 
col=lvl_colors  )
```

[image]